# Группировка ссылок на модели и сортивка в кастомном порядке в админке

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, админка

Есть ли способ сгруппировать модели в админке в собственные группы, а не по приложениям без создания новых приложений и прокси-моделей? Нужно для `Django 3.1.X+`

Comment: https://github.com/maykinmedia/django-admin-index